# If there is no discount hide table row in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to implement the code below when a discount is applied to an order on my Woocommerce store. Right now, it shows every time a product is added. I am discounting all orders 15% when 5 or more products are added to the cart. But if I only add 2 products the table row still shows (and it shows $40 which is odd). It works great when 5 or more items are added to the cart. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
    <th><?php esc_html_e( '15% Discount', 'beaux' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php esc_html_e( '-', 'beaux' ); ?><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did it using woocommerce templates, it's better to use hooks:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'ywp_custom_total_message_html' );
function ywp_custom_total_message_html( $value ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    if( $cart_item_count >= 5 ) {
        $value .= esc_html_e( '15% Discount', 'beaux' ) . '<br />';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in `functions.php` of your active theme/child theme. Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of items in the cart using `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`.

```php
<?php if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() >= 5 ): ?>
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
<th><?php esc_html_e( '15% Discount', 'beaux' ); ?></th>
<td><?php esc_html_e( '-', 'beaux' ); ?><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just replace your snippet by this one. If less than 5 items are in the cart, the discount won't show.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this hides the discount for 5 products or more as well.

Comment: I've edited the answer, changed to `>= 5`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, that didn't work either.